# Create database from sqlplus / as sysdba

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am using CentOs and Oracle 10 XE.

I start database in nomount at sqlplus / as sysdba 
and I want to create database name XE from script can someone help ?

```
CREATE DATABASE XE
USER SYS IDENTIFIED BY oracle
USER SYSTEM IDENTIFIED BY oracle
LOGFILE GROUP 1 ('/usr/lib/oracle/xe/oradata/XE/log/redo01.log') SIZE 100M,
GROUP 2 ('/usr/lib/oracle/xe/oradata/XE/log/redo02.log') SIZE 100M,
GROUP 3 ('/usr/lib/oracle/xe/oradata/XE/log/redo03.log') SIZE 100M
DATAFILE '/usr/lib/oracle/xe/oradata/XE/system01.dbf' SIZE 325M REUSE
SYSAUX DATAFILE '/usr/lib/oracle/xe/oradata/XE/sysaux01.dbf' SIZE 325M REUSE
DEFAULT TABLESPACE tbs_1
DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE tempts1
TEMPFILE '/usr/lib/oracle/xe/oradata/XE/temp01.dbf'
SIZE 20M REUSE;
```

And I get the following error :

```
Completed: ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMPTS1
Tue May 14 09:54:06 2019
Errors in file /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/admin/XE/udump/xe_ora_17320.trc:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-02236: invalid file name
Tue May 14 09:54:06 2019
Errors in file /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/admin/XE/udump/xe_ora_17320.trc:
ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed
ORA-01519: error while processing file '?/rdbms/admin/sql.bsq' near line 6262
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-02236: invalid file name
Error 1519 happened during db open, shutting down database
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but: as you use Oracle 10g Express Edition (XE), well - you'd rather stop doing what you are doing. There's no way to create more than one database in XE (and that one was already created during the installation process).

If you want to practice your DBA skills regarding new databases, download Standard (or Enterprise) edition and do it there. Note that 10g isn't available any more.